# Getting Linker error while instantiating a template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

While instantiating the `class` in `main` I am getting these two errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall templateClass<int>::templateClass<int>(void)" (??0?$templateClass@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall templateClass<int>::~templateClass<int>(void)" (??1?$templateClass@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

### Code

#### `templateClass.h`

```
#pragma once

#define MAX 10

template<class T>
class templateClass
{

private:
    T arr[MAX];
    int size;
public:
    templateClass(void);
    void initArrayWithZero();
    void pushElementIntoArray(T element );
    void printArray();
    ~templateClass(void);
};
```

#### `templateclass.c`

```
#include "templateClass.h"

template <class T>
templateClass<T>::templateClass(void)
{
    size = 0;
}

template <class T>
templateClass<T>::~templateClass(void)
{
}

template <class T>
void templateClass<T>::pushElementIntoArray(T element )
{
    if(size<MAX)
    {
        T[size++] = element;
    }
    else
    {
        //Give error code
    }
}

template <class T>
void templateClass<T>::initArrayWithZero()
{
    for(i= 0; i<MAX; i++)
        T[i] = 0;
}

template <class T>
void templateClass<T>::printArray()
{
    for( int i =0; i<MAX; i++)
        cout<<"\n"T[i];
}
```

#### `Main.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "templateClass.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    templateClass<int> intarray;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Template classes such as `templateClass<T>` must (usually) be implemented in header (`.h`) files.

As such, you need to move the content of `templateclass.c` to `templateClass.h` and delete `templateclass.c`.

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/78845) for more information.

Comment: But I am getting another error when I am trying to print the elements of array .
error C2275: 'T' : illegal use of this type as an expression
  for( int i =0; i<MAX; i++)
   cout<<T[i];

Comment: @Maddyfire: Happy to help. Your next problem is that `T` is the *type* and `arr` is the *variable*. You probably meant `for (int i = 0; i< MAX; i++) { std::cout << "\n" << arr[i]; }` (or similar).